# How to get the user of a Tridion Publish Event?

Tags: publishing, event-system

I did a small publish event listener using the following code:

```
[TcmExtension("TridionPPQEventSystem")]
public class PPQEventHandler : TcmExtension
{
    public PPQEventHandler()
    {
        Subscribe();
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        EventSystem.Subscribe<Page, PublishEventArgs>(OnPagePublishPre, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
    }

    private void OnPagePublishPre(Page page, PublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        //....some code here
    }
}
```

My question is, how to get the User who initiated the publishing? So far I have only found the user who last saved the page (Page.Revisor), but not the one who published it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the user who published, you need to use

```
PublishTransaction.Creator
```

Here `Creator` returns the `User` Object.

```
private void OnPagePublishPre(Page page, PublishEventArgs mPublishEventArgs, EventPhases phase)
{
    List<PublishTransaction> mPublishTransactionList = mPublishEventArgs.PublishTransactions.ToList();

    foreach (PublishTransaction mPublishTransaction in mPublishTransactionList)
    {
        // Returns the User Title
        String publishedUser = mPublishTransaction.Creator.Title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here just for your reference I pasted a code to get the user and also Groupname if you publish any component.

```
private void PublishingFinish(Component subject, PublishEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
        {
            User user = subject.Session.User;           
            foreach (GroupMembership group in user.GroupMemberships)
            {
                group.Group.Title;
            }    
        }
```